# Special Steps for Rails Deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I'm Deploying a rails app on the server for production? What are the special steps, I should follow in production installation, that is different from development.

I've installed passenger, passenger-apache2-module
I've also run bundle install --deployment

What are other special treatments, I should use for production?

Thanks.

Comment: do you use **capistrano**? if so, copy-paste **config/deploy.rb** to us to review

Comment: No. I don't use capistrano yet. I was looking to deploy a rails app manually. I did it with the help of Git and Shell. Thanks :)

Comment: deploy a Rails application "manually"? how can it be, you should teach us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With our deployment servers we have a fairly easy setup

- ubuntu
- apache + passenger
- a rails user from where the apps are
  actually run "/home/rails/apps/fancy_app_name"
- and we have a webistrano app running to handle the deployments (so our development
  machines don't have to be aware of all production steps)